# What CPU is equivalent? Moving from VPS to Dedicated Server.

Tags: vps, central-processing-unit, dedicated-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I want to move from VPS to Dedicated Server I guess that VPS specifications are not equal to Dedicated Server and I predict that Dedicated server can make more work with less power. Does someone tried that?

I use right now **VPS** with the next specifications:
CPU 4 cores 2,5 GHz
3 GB RAM

Note: I dont know what model of CPU they use, the maximum combination is 8GHz and 24GB RAM.

For the same price I can have **Dedicated Server**:
Intel Core i3 2130 3.4 GHz (2 cores, 4 threads)
16GB RAM DDR3

With the RAM I dont have doubts, it will be enough for 1 or 2 years with site growth (IPB forum). My doubt is the next: **Its much better this 2 cores Intel 3.4GHz than my VPS 4 cores 2,5GHz?**

Thanks in advance to all who write his opinion.

Comment: *Note: I dont know what model of CPU they use* - then how can you possibly ask us for equivalent CPUs? You're asking us to compare "something, whatever" to "I don't know". You're never going to get a good answer from that start, and that's even before thinking about the points Chopper makes about needing to benchmark your specific code on both platforms to get a true answer...

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking this question is unanswerable - the only way to know what is equivalent would be to understand what you're running on this server (you don't even mention an OS!) and for you to benchmark that code on both machines.

That said an i3 is barely a desktop CPU, it's certainly not a server one so I wouldn't recommend you to use that, *maybe* an i7 but I'd stick to server CPUs if I were you, they degrade far more gracefully under pressure.

Comment: Sor for not writing important info. The OS is CentOS 6, I have IPBoard 3.3 forum. With more than 150 connections at the time to database. With 25% more money I cant get Intel Core i5-2400, but Intel i7 I cant pay right now. see the Stats of my VPS right now fist hours are the top of usage. http://i45.tinypic.com/33xvbb6.png